# How to call action class using <a href> tag

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

The following code is giving error as:

> There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name
>   .

code:
.jsp file:

```
<a href="<s:url action='DisconnectAction' />">Disconnect</a>
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="DisconnectAction" class="ActionPackages.DisconnectAction">
    <result name="success">/JSP/mytemplate.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/JSP/mytemplate.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/JSP/mytemplate.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/JSP/mytemplate.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I want to perform action and keep the current accessing page only which is mytemplate.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear so better give details about the problem but if i read the subject  you want to call action using  so here is the struts2 standard way

```
<s:a cssClass="table_tabs_dis" href="%{GenURL}">General</s:a>
```

and here is one more

```
<a href="<s:url action=MyAction" namespace="/abc/xyz" />">ClickME</a>
```

Comment: Hi i changed the code and it worked fine instead of writing as    <a href="<s:url action='DisconnectAction' />">Disconnect</a>       i wrote it as <a href="DisconnectAction" />Disconnect</a>

Answer (score 0):

According to your question the problem was in your `<s:url/>` tag you have to give `action` after DisconnectAction & it will work fine as you want.

```
<a href="<s:url action="DisconnectAction.action"/>">Disconnect</a>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="DisconnectAction" class="ActionPackages.DisconnectAction">
    <result name="success">/JSP/mytemplate.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/JSP/mytemplate.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/JSP/mytemplate.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/JSP/mytemplate.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: I don't think this is true; the action extension should not be required in an `<s:url/>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not given **".action "** extension in struts  tag.
When you are using

```
<s:form action="someAction"></s:form>
```

you dont need to give .action extension to your action name.
But since you are embedding it in  HTML tag, you have to give .action Extension.

**(Answer Verified on Live)**

```
 <a href="<s:url action="urlTagAction.action" />"> Disconnect </a>
```